Azure OpenAI GPT-4o mini Structured Outputs `response_format` not working
trying to replicate the math tutor example using Azure OpenAI API, but response_format is flagged as "Invalid parameter".
Full error message:
{
    "name": "BadRequestError",
    "message": "Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': \"Invalid parameter: 'response_format' must be one of 'json_object', 'text'.\", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'response_format', 'code': None}}",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 55
     25 response_format ={
     26     \"type\": \"json_schema\",
     27     \"json_schema\": {
   (...)
     50     }
     51 }
     54 # Ask the model to use the function
---> 55 response = client.chat.completions.create(
     56     model=deployment_name,
     57     messages=messages,
     58     response_format=response_format,
     59 )
     61 json.loads(response.choices[0].message.tool_calls[0].function.arguments)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\_utils\\_utils.py:277, in required_args.<locals>.inner.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    275             msg = f\"Missing required argument: {quote(missing[0])}\"
    276     raise TypeError(msg)
--> 277 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\resources\\chat\\completions.py:590, in Completions.create(self, messages, model, frequency_penalty, function_call, functions, logit_bias, logprobs, max_tokens, n, presence_penalty, response_format, seed, stop, stream, stream_options, temperature, tool_choice, tools, top_logprobs, top_p, user, extra_headers, extra_query, extra_body, timeout)
    558 @required_args([\"messages\", \"model\"], [\"messages\", \"model\", \"stream\"])
    559 def create(
    560     self,
   (...)
    588     timeout: float | httpx.Timeout | None | NotGiven = NOT_GIVEN,
    589 ) -> ChatCompletion | Stream[ChatCompletionChunk]:
--> 590     return self._post(
    591         \"/chat/completions\",
    592         body=maybe_transform(
    593             {
    594                 \"messages\": messages,
    595                 \"model\": model,
    596                 \"frequency_penalty\": frequency_penalty,
    597                 \"function_call\": function_call,
    598                 \"functions\": functions,
    599                 \"logit_bias\": logit_bias,
    600                 \"logprobs\": logprobs,
    601                 \"max_tokens\": max_tokens,
    602                 \"n\": n,
    603                 \"presence_penalty\": presence_penalty,
    604                 \"response_format\": response_format,
    605                 \"seed\": seed,
    606                 \"stop\": stop,
    607                 \"stream\": stream,
    608                 \"stream_options\": stream_options,
    609                 \"temperature\": temperature,
    610                 \"tool_choice\": tool_choice,
    611                 \"tools\": tools,
    612                 \"top_logprobs\": top_logprobs,
    613                 \"top_p\": top_p,
    614                 \"user\": user,
    615             },
    616             completion_create_params.CompletionCreateParams,
    617         ),
    618         options=make_request_options(
    619             extra_headers=extra_headers, extra_query=extra_query, extra_body=extra_body, timeout=timeout
    620         ),
    621         cast_to=ChatCompletion,
    622         stream=stream or False,
    623         stream_cls=Stream[ChatCompletionChunk],
    624     )

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\_base_client.py:1240, in SyncAPIClient.post(self, path, cast_to, body, options, files, stream, stream_cls)
   1226 def post(
   1227     self,
   1228     path: str,
   (...)
   1235     stream_cls: type[_StreamT] | None = None,
   1236 ) -> ResponseT | _StreamT:
   1237     opts = FinalRequestOptions.construct(
   1238         method=\"post\", url=path, json_data=body, files=to_httpx_files(files), **options
   1239     )
-> 1240     return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\_base_client.py:921, in SyncAPIClient.request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
    912 def request(
    913     self,
    914     cast_to: Type[ResponseT],
   (...)
    919     stream_cls: type[_StreamT] | None = None,
    920 ) -> ResponseT | _StreamT:
--> 921     return self._request(
    922         cast_to=cast_to,
    923         options=options,
    924         stream=stream,
    925         stream_cls=stream_cls,
    926         remaining_retries=remaining_retries,
    927     )

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\openai\\_base_client.py:1020, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
   1017         err.response.read()
   1019     log.debug(\"Re-raising status error\")
-> 1020     raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
   1022 return self._process_response(
   1023     cast_to=cast_to,
   1024     options=options,
   (...)
   1027     stream_cls=stream_cls,
   1028 )

BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': \"Invalid parameter: 'response_format' must be one of 'json_object', 'text'.\", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'response_format', 'code': None}}"
}

code:
import os
import json
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from textwrap import dedent

# Initialize the Azure OpenAI client
client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"), 
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),  
    api_version=os.getenv("OpenAI_API_VERSION")
)
deployment_name = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ID")

# Initial user message
messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": dedent("""
        You are a helpful math tutor. You will be provided with a math problem,
        and your goal will be to output a step by step solution, along with a final answer.
        For each step, just provide the output as an equation use the explanation field to detail the reasoning.
                                         """)},
    {"role": "user", "content": "solve 8x + 31 = 2"}
]

# Define the JSON schema for structured output
response_format ={
    "type": "json_schema",
    "json_schema": {
        "name": "math_reasoning",
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "steps": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "explanation": {"type": "string"},
                            "output": {"type": "string"}
                        },
                        "required": ["explanation", "output"],
                        "additionalProperties": False
                    }
                },
                "final_answer": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": ["steps", "final_answer"],
            "additionalProperties": False
        },
        "strict": True
    }
}


# Ask the model to use the function
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=deployment_name,
    messages=messages,
    response_format=response_format,
)

json.loads(response.choices[0].message.tool_calls[0].function.arguments)



"Invalid parameter: 'response_format' must be one of 'json_object' = try to check the type of your response_format variable = i.e. print(type(response_format)) and see if this variable is a valid json object. I'm not sure, but, try to close the True and False as strings - i.e. ("strict": "true") and try again your code.

I reached out to Azure Support regarding this and what I have been told that support for json_schema is not available with OpenAI models in Azure just yet. You might want to wait for some time.

Apparently, this is not yet supported in Azure. Others have raised this in Microsoft discussions here and here as well, however no ETA for the fix yet.
While waiting for the issue to be resolved by the Azure's team, I'd suggest to follow "Native SDK support" section of this article. Use the function-calling option with AzureOpenAI's gpt-4o model (I ran into issues while trying gpt-4o-mini model). That should still give you the json output and the code you use there is pretty similar to the "response_format" (not yet supported) option and you can easily update your code when Azure supports the "response_format" option.
Updates on Sept 3rd:

Starting from Sept 3rd 2024, AzureOpenAI also supports Structured Output option for the gpt-4o models link1, link2.

My instruction above that used to work with gpt-4o-2024-05-13 model is no longer works. That produces the following error if tried with gpt-4o-2024-05-13 model:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Invalid function definition for 'Query': unexpected parameter 'strict' parameter supplied.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}


I've reported that to Microsoft team in one of the comments here. Now that gpt-4o-2024-08-06 is supported, switching to that should work, however, the response is slow (comparing to gpt-4o-2024-05-13 model).

Just today support was announced for GPT-4o (not mini).
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/introducing-gpt-4o-2024-08-06-api-with-structured-outputs-on/ba-p/4232684

Structured output format is not yet supported for Azure OpenAI gpt-4o-mini models, even though OpenAI supports it - https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/structured-outputs/structured-outputs-vs-json-mode
You can use it with gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model as per this latest announcement- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/introducing-gpt-4o-2024-08-06-api-with-structured-outputs-on/ba-p/4232684
For gpt-4o-mini, you'd have to stick with
"response_format": { "type": "json_object" }

and specify the expected json format/schema in your prompts.
